# The warning about my Private Information is inaccurate; name changes don't affect my developer story

Tags: bug, profile-page, developer-story

If I begin changing my name in my Private Information on the [Edit Profile & Settings page](https://stackoverflow.com/users/edit/current), the following notice shows up (bold present in the original):

> ⚠️ Updates to your **Full name** will be reflected within your Developer Story and/or all Stack Overflow Teams. Within Developer Story, your name is seen by employers and visitors to your public CV/Story. Within Stack Overflow for Teams, your name is seen by members of that team.

Here's a screenshot, I'll update my “Full name” to “test name”:

> [image]

This warning isn't actually accurate. Having **saved my profile like this,** my new full name of “test name” hasn't been reflected anywhere I can see on my developer story. It still lists a display name I chose earlier, and my actual full name chosen earlier.

> [image]

Something about that warning isn't quite right and ought to get updated.

FWIW though, I consider the fact this doesn't update my full name on my developer story to be a **feature.** I don't want the full name on my profile, and my full name on my developer story, to overlap — because the full name I choose on my profile is also a public-facing channels name, and I don't want that to be my real life name. On that account I consider the bug to be better resolved by updating the warning.